# Added new items dynamycally with ajax

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a piece of html code using Thymeleaf:

```
<form id="form" action="/create" th:action="@{/create}" th:object="${form}">

   <input type="text" th:field="*{title}"/>

   <div th:each="item, itemInfo : *{items}">
      <div>
         <input type="text" th:field="*{items[__${itemInfo.index}__].text}" />
      </div>
   </div>

   <button id="addNewBtn" onClick="add()"/>

   <button type="submit" value="Create"/>

</form>
```

form object has a collection called 'items'. Clicking on the button 'addNewBtn' invokes javascript method 'add' where it must contain the code which can add new item to the collection (and this is my problem here - I don't know how this code looks like).
Is here any way to add new item to the collection using ajax? It's also important that new added item must be binded with field called 'text'.
Or probably there is another solution ? Basically, I need to create the object (after submit form) with title and a lot of items with text which can be added dynamically by an user.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is "Items" when the page is initially rendered? Is it empty?

Comment: no, they are not empty. By default this collection contains 2 objects with field: String text, and some other fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can call (using ajax) the HTML row template from the server by giving an 'index' parameter.

Comment: Could you give an example ? I wonder how binding will work in this case

Comment: I dont have example of that but I think it should works aswell. You can check this post that I described how I do the same thing without ajax. http://blog.florentlim.com/how-to-write-javascript-including-thymeleaf/
It not using ajax but it create a new row dynamically for a later binding.
Hope it can help you